# Can the Defense Production Act grant immunity to civil liability?

Tags: united-states, president, executive, pandemic

Trump has said that he's going to give liability protections to meat processing plants in case employees catch COVID-19 at work.  The executive order itself [is here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/executive-order-delegating-authority-dpa-respect-food-supply-chain-resources-national-emergency-caused-outbreak-covid-19/).  Cited in the order is [the Defense Production Act of 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Production_Act_of_1950).

Does that Act grant the President the authority to give private companies protection from civil liability cases?  (This is assuming, for the sake of the argument, that the Defense Production Act applies to a pandemic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sec. 707 of that law](https://govtrackus.s3.amazonaws.com/legislink/pdf/stat/64/STATUTE-64-Pg798b.pdf) addresses the matter of liability:

> No person shall be held liable for damages or penalties for any act
>   or failure to act resulting directly or indirectly from his compliance
>   with a rule, regulation, or order issued pursuant to this Act,
>   notwithstanding that any such rule, regulation, or order shall
>   thereafter be declared by judicial or other competent authority to be
>   invalid.